# Add new column to Numpy Array as a function of the rows

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 2D Numpy Array, and I want to apply a function to each of the rows and form a new column (the new first column) with the results. For example, let

```
M = np.array([[1,0,1], [0,0,1]])
```

and I want to apply the `sum` function on each row and get

```
array([[2,1,0,1], [1,0,0,1]])
```

So the first column is `[2,1]`, the sum of the first row and the second row.

Comment: Make a 1 column array with the new values, and concatenate them.

Comment: `np.column_stack((M.sum(1), M))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can generally append arrays to each other using `np.concatenate` when they have similar dimensionality. You can guarantee that `sum` will retain dimensionality regardless of axis using the `keepdims` argument:

```
np.concatenate((M.sum(axis=1, keepdims=True), M), axis=1)
```

This is equivalent to

```
np.concatenate((M.sum(1)[:, None], M), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another similar way:

```
np.insert(M, 0, M.sum(1), 1)
```

output:

```
array([[2, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 1]])
```